# Glade and GTK: which version to choose?

Tags: linux, gtk, glade

I'm new to Linux C/C++ GUI programming. 
I Installed the following on Linux Mint 17.1 KDE:

> 1. Code::Blocks 13.12
> 2. GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3
> 3. Glade 3.8.0 and 3.16.1. I'm not sure so I installed both.

But what are the differences? The only thing I can see is 3.8.0 has no "edit widget margin" and "edit widget alignment". I don't understand. I know 3.8.x is for GTK+ 2 and > 3.16 is for GTK+ 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up a GUI-toolkit, in this case GTK, with the GUI-designer, in this case Glade. A GUI can be constructed using the appropriate language bindings, or by using a GUI designer. In the case of Glade, the layout of the GUI will be saved as an XML-file (`*.glade`) that you can load from inside your applications code.

You should probably read through some of these pages:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_GTK%2B
- http://www.gtkmm.org/en/
- http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html
- http://www.micahcarrick.com/12-24-2007/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html